# OpenLayers JS - How to distinguish between user and programmatic view changes?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a 'moveend' listener established on an OpenLayers map. I can pan or zoom the map and the listener fires as expected.  I also have the need in this app to programmatically change the zoom and the center location, however, when I do the 'moveend' listener fires. Is it possible to distinguish between user-driven view changes and programmatic view changes in OpenLayers?

I am using JavaScript OpenLayers version 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to distingish.  But here's what you can do.  When you programmatically zoom or change the center location, you can temporarily unregister the moveend event, and then re-register it afterwards:

map.events.unregister( "moveend", map, function );
.
.
programatically zoom
.
.
map.events.register( "moveend", map, function );

Answer (score 0):

Also, when zooming or moving map programmaticaly, you could set some variable to true.

In listener, check that variable. If it's true, map is moved programmaticaly. After checking, set it back to false.